# Linq expression where clause with generic type

Tags: linq, generics, types, lambda, where-clause

In my Data access layer,  I am calling the GET method with the following Lambda expression :

`public List<T> Get<T>() where T : class
{
   var list = Context.Set<T>().ToList().Distinct().Where(x => x.Content_type == "Test");
   return list;
}`

But getting error

> "Cannot resolve symbol Content_type"

How can i resolve this issue ?

Comment: A side note: you should really chain the calls in reverse order - `Where` then `Distinct` then `ToList`.

Comment: thansk @IvanStoev, I am new to LINQ queries/ Lambda expressions and still learning. Just curious how that will change the result. I verified the results from my database and it is the same.

Comment: It will not change the result, but the processing place. The way you wrote it it will read all the table records in memory and then do filtering etc., while in the second scenario all the filtering will be done inside the database.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that `Content_type` is not a part of T class because it's just a class.

As @tchelidze says, you can set a where clause on your function to specify a type, like this :

```
public List<T> Get<T>() where T : IYourCommonInterface
{
    var list = Context.Set<T>().Where(x => x.Content_type == "Test").Distinct().ToList();
    return list;
}
```

But if you need to be totaly generic, you can add a selector to your function like this :

```
public List<T> Get<T>(Func<T, object> selector) where T : class
{
    var list = Context.Set<T>().Where(x => selector(x) == "Test").Distinct().ToList();
    return list;
}
```

And use it like that :

```
Get(x => x.Content_type);
```

Also, if you want to go further, you can pass the entire condition :

```
public List<T> Get<T>(Func<T, bool> condition) where T : class
{
    var list = Context.Set<T>().Where(condition).Distinct().ToList();
    return list;
}
```

And use it like this :

```
Get(x => x.Content_type == "test");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Floc, great answer, thanks for showing passing the where condition!

Answer (score 1):

Reason is that all you know about `T` is that it is a `class`. You do not know if it contains `Content_type` property or not. 
If you always pass `T` class which contains definition for `Content_type` try following . 
  `Context.Set<T>().ToList().Distinct().Where(x => (x as SomeClassWithContentTypeField).Content_type == "Test");` 
Better way will be if you introduce interface `IHasContentTypeField` which declared `Content_type` property

```
public interface IHasContentTypeField
{
  string Content_type { get; set; }
}
```

then constraint `T` to this interface.

```
public List<T> Get<T>() where T : IHasContentTypeField
```

Then you can implement `IHasContentTypeField` in classes for which you want to call `Get<T>` method.

```
public class A : IHasContentTypeField
{
  public string Content_type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that in my case there can be two possibilities for the type T and luckily both the types has the field Content Type.

Comment: @pikachu Pretty good, Implement `IHasContentTypeField` interface int both of them. and you are good to go.

Comment: I am a bit confused about this interface, in my case there can be multiple classes with one of the properties as Content_type. Can you explain in more detail.

Comment: I am using entity framework and the class(having the field Content_type)  is one of my domain models. Will it be a right approach to create an interface.

Comment: @pikachu You should use interfaces in order to manage call `Get` method properly (you are dealing with `Generics`). It does not matter which ORM are you using.