# How to use LINQ Where for generic type?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following generic method that I need to be able to perform a LINQ Where query in:

```
public static List<T> GetItems<T>(Guid parentId = new Guid()) where T : new()
{
    var db = new SQLiteConnection(_dbPath);
    List<T> result;

    if (parentId != Guid.Empty)
    {
        result = db.Table<T>().Where(i => i.ParentId.Equals(parentId)).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        result = db.Table<T>().ToList();
    }

    db.Close();
    return result;
}
```

The compiler doesn't like the following line

```
result = db.Table<T>().Where(i => i.ParentId.Equals(parentId)).ToList();
```

> error: cannot resolve 'ParentId'

Is it possible to use generics in this way in a LINQ query? Note that object of type T will always have a ParentId property.

Comment: Can you create an interface that exposes the `ParentId` and use that as a constraint of the generic type?

Comment: If T has ParentId -property, you KNOW the type. For very least it's an interface with that one property.

Comment: what is the error!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# lambda query using generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37294374/c-sharp-lambda-query-using-generic-type)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq expression where clause with generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34921459/linq-expression-where-clause-with-generic-type)

Comment: @Ajay - I mentioned the error in my OP - "cannot resolve 'ParentId'".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should concretize `T` parameter with some interface which will include required values. Also, you should add this interface to all types that contains this field or base type for its classes.

```
public interface IHierarchy
{
    public Guid ParentId { get; }
}

public static List<T> GetItems<T>(Guid parentId = new Guid()) 
    where T : IHierarchy, new()
{
    var db = new SQLiteConnection(_dbPath);
    List<T> result;

    if (parentId != Guid.Empty)
    {
        result = db.Table<T>().Where(i => i.ParentId.Equals(parentId)).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        result = db.Table<T>().ToList();
    }

    db.Close();
    return result;
}
```

If you have 2 types of entities and the first contains required values and the second  does not, then you can have two overloads for this scenario.

Comment: Not sure what's the `new()` constraint doing there

Comment: @Vadim Martynov  - Thanks, the change to the method signature is what I was looking for. I already had an interface defining T so just added that to the signature as per your example.

Answer (score 6):

You used a generic type and the compiler don't know which `entity` are you going to use.

Just use `reflection` feature of `.NET` language.

```
result = db.Table<T>().Where(i => i.GetType().GetProperty("ParentId").GetValue(src, null).Equals(parentId)).ToList();
```

Comment: Wow I'm not sure that this solution will work because the author uses LINQ in SQL context and where clause should be transformable to SQL language.

Comment: This is perfectly working solution when trying to be more generic when doing LINQ with list manipulations.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that in your code you assume that every `T` has a GUID property `ParentId`, while in fact you only required that every T has a default constructor. You need to require that every T has a ParentId.

You could do this by requiring that every T implements some interface. Like other answers suggest, however this is quite a nuisance, because for every class that you want to use this function for you'll need to implement this interface.

The function `Enumerable.Where` seems to be able to do the same job, without requiring any interface from the input items. So let's use the same method:

As input we tell which property to use (in your case ParentId) and with which value to compare (in your case parentId).

The only requirement we have is that we must be able to compare ParentId with parentId: it should be IEquatable

```
public List<T> GetItems<T, TKey>(Func<T, TKey> keySelector, Tkey value)
    TKey : IEquatable<TKey>,
{
    ...
     result = db.Table<T>()
       .Where(t => keySelector(t).Equals(value))
       .ToList();
}
```

Usage:

```
    Guid value = ...
    var items = GetItems<MyClass, Guid>(item => item.ParentId, value);
```

This function will also work with other classes and other properties:

```
int studentId = ...
var students = GetItems<Student, int>(student => student.Id, studentId);
var otherStudents = GetItems<Student, string>(student => student.Name, "John");
```

Two side remarks:
 - you use `new Guid()` to define some default `Guid`. It is faster to use `Guid.Empty`
 - You will not create new items of type T. They are already in your dbContext.Table. Therefore you don't need new().
 - However, if your Table requires that T is a class then you should require that. See your Table definition:

```
where T : class
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. When I try to use Guid.Empty as a default parameter value though, I get the following compiler error: Default parameter value for 'parentId' must be a compile-time constant.

Comment: Guid.Empty is an already existing object. You cannot assign it to compile time constants. However you can assign it to variables, even if they are readonly. You can also use it in comparison. You want to use it as default parameter value. Maybe better to create two functions one without parameters that calls the other one with value Guid.Empty(). Now I understand why all LINQ functions have two versions: one without EqualityComparer and one with Comparer, instead of using default initialization of comparer parameter